# Neutron reflectivity/X-ray reflectivity vs critical angle

Tags: reflection, neutrons, x-rays

I am trying to write a code that calculates Neutron/X-ray reflectivity profile of a multilayered system using Parrat algorithm. I am wondering what to do for $Q$ values below the critical $Q$ edge (where total internal reflection occurs). Most of the graphs that I have come across in journal papers have intensity scaled to $1$ below the critical edge.

[image]
[image]
I am wondering if there are any analytical solutions for $Q$ tending to zero, so that I get a smooth transition to $R=1$.

Fresnel reflectivity does not hold at small angles and violates the condition that $R\leq1$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I learned to approach this problem (in the neutron case) using a symmetries argument. Consider the problem from a reference frame where the neutron's momentum parallel to the mirror surface is zero. In that frame you have a classic one-dimensional quantum mechanics problem: a low-energy particle in vacuum is approaching a potential barrier (given by the Fermi pseudopotential) and you can compute the probabilities for external reflection and for transmission. Neglecting absorption, those are the only two possibilities. If the perpendicular part of the neutron's kinetic energy is less than the pseudopotential barrier, the reflection probability really is unity; for slightly larger energies, you computed the reflection probabilities in intro QM.